# network policy + WPA enterprise (tkip) Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, wifi, wpa, nps

hi I've attempted the following guide and in a bit of a pickle.
http://techblog.mirabito.net.au/?p=87

My main goal is to have a username / password based wireless authentication with active directory integration.

I keep getting the error

Network Policy Server denied access to a user.

Contact the Network Policy Server administrator for more information.
User:
    Security ID:            domain\rhysbeta
    Account Name:           rhysbeta
    Account Domain:         domain
    Fully Qualified Account Name:   domain\rhysbeta

Client Machine:
    Security ID:            NULL SID
    Account Name:           -
    Fully Qualified Account Name:   -
    OS-Version:         -
    Called Station Identifier:      00-12-BF-00-71-3C:wirelessname
    Calling Station Identifier:     00-23-76-5D-1E-31

NAS:
    NAS IPv4 Address:       0.0.0.0
    NAS IPv6 Address:       -
    NAS Identifier:         -
    NAS Port-Type:          Wireless - IEEE 802.11
    NAS Port:           2

RADIUS Client:
    Client Friendly Name:       Belkin54g
    Client IP Address:          x.x.x.10

Authentication Details:
    Connection Request Policy Name: Secure Wireless Connections
    Network Policy Name:        Secure Wireless Connections
    Authentication Provider:        Windows
    Authentication Server:      srvr.example.com
    Authentication Type:        EAP
    EAP Type:           -
    Account Session Identifier:     -
    Logging Results:            Accounting information was written to the local log file.
    Reason Code:            22
    Reason:             The client could not be authenticated  because the Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP) Type cannot be processed by the server.
`

I would love to have it so that non domain devices

Comment: Does your NPS server have a valid machine certificate?

Comment: Yep, but not a global verified only self signed by PDC.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're experiencing the same issue on some Ubuntu machines here.. The EAP Type should say "Microsoft: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP v2)" but it is blank.

Comment: To be honest I have completely forgotten about this project, I know I got it working in the end, I'll have a look in work tomorrow and report back

Answer (score 0):

Start diagnosting from CAPI2 (Eventlog -> Applications and Services -> Microsoft -> CAPI2 -> Operational -> Enable). There are tons of things you can miss.
First diagnose on client side, second on server side. 
There also was an issue with SChannel when you have too many trusted Root CAs installed on your system.